# Nested while loop of next() is not working after first iteration while retrieving data from DB

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, jdbc, jsp-tags

I was about to display questions and their respective options from the questionsDB and optionsDB.
I have create two result sets and two queries to do the stuff in nested loop.It works fine in first iteration by displaying the first question and its respective options but after that its not iterating the data.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>

<%
String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String dbName = "onlinefeedback";
String userId = "root";
String password = "123456";

try {
    Class.forName(driverName);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet resultQuestions = null;
ResultSet resultOptions = null;

try{ 
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl+dbName, userId, password);
    statement=connection.createStatement();
    String qsql ="SELECT * FROM questionsDB";

    resultQuestions = statement.executeQuery(qsql);
    
    while(resultQuestions.next()) {
        int curQuestion= Integer.parseInt(resultQuestions.getString("qid"));
%>

<%= resultQuestions.getString("qid") %>
<%=resultQuestions.getString("questionmessage") %>
<% 
String osql ="SELECT * FROM optionsDB WHERE qid="+curQuestion;
resultOptions = statement.executeQuery(osql); 
%>

<%      while(resultOptions.next()) {
%>
            <%=resultOptions.getString("optionmessage") %>
<%  
        }
    }
//connection.close();
} 
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: You can easily solve this by using a single query with a join. It will likely perform better than your current N+1 query problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a separate statement for the options retrieval query. As per [Statement documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Statement.html):

> By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open
> at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is
> interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated
> by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement
> interface implicitly close a current ResultSet object of the statement
> if an open one exists.